# Is it bad practice to use co-dependent classes?

Tags: c++, oop, header, dependencies

If I have a `Container` class which holds a bunch of `Component` objects (similar to Java's UI framework), would it be poor style/practice to keep track of the `Container` parent within each `Component`?

This ends up causing some strange compiler issues because the `Component` includes the header file for `Container` and vice-versa. Even with a header guard fix, I end up having to declare a prototype `class Component;` on top of the `Container` header, and similarly for `Component`.

It seems like you have to go through quite a bit of trouble to get a two-way interaction between two classes. Would it be advisable to look for another solution to the problem that co-dependency "solves" or is this convoluted implementation expected from C++ and I should just suck it up?

**EDIT:** Perhaps some context/reasoning would help. The reason I'm using this co-dependency is because I need to notify the parent when a child's destructor has been called (so it can be removed from the list of children), and I also need to have the drawn position of the child be relative to that of the parent.

Thanks,
Jengerer

Comment: I removed the C tag, because this is really a C++ question.

Comment: Not obvious to me that the GUI tag is appropriate either - will leave it to Jengerer to reconsider that.

Comment: Well, the `Component` and `Container` classes are for a GUI that I'm working on in C++. I agree it's not all that necessary, though.

Comment: If a class contains only a reference or a pointer then you don't need the full definition and thus you can forward declare it rather than include the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think it's a design problem. You really should look at the design as a whole and see if you can design it better. Ask yourself why you have the dependent classes requiring access to the container. Perhaps the container is providing functionality it should not. Can this functionality be provided in another way?

Comment: The main problems that I tried to solve using this design were:
a) When a `Component` is destroyed, I want to notify the parent that it should be removed from the list of children.
b) When a `Component` is drawn to the screen, I want it to draw itself relative to the parent's position.

How could I solve these issues without using these dependent classes? I can't really think of a way that's much neater than this one.

Comment: Hmm, Firstly - where is the code that destroys the component? Perhaps this should be a function of the container so that it can both delete the component and remove it from the local list. And the same with the draw function. The containers draw function can instruct each component to draw, giving it an x/y position to start at. In other words with both the delete and draw functions, why not make the container the main entry point. Another option is to look at using an observer pattern where the reference back to the container is through an interface.

Comment: Good idea, I think I may end up going with this suggestion. I actually considered setting the position of the child externally, but I hesitated because I didn't like having to calculate it each time, but I realized that this is essentially already what my program does, only the position is calculated in the child instead.

Answer (score 3):

Having a component keep a pointer to its parent is widely used, and I don't see it as bad practice. It can be used for a variety of things, from working up trees of widgets to handling lost or leaked components.

To work around the issue with the compiler, you'll need to either put the include lines inside header guards, or have a third file with forward declarations for both classes (in the appropriate namespace).

I've seen the latter done in a few large OO libraries, and it is usually then included by almost every other file in the project. While that can lead to a bit of namespace pollution, it has some benefits (not needing to include the full class definition or dependencies of another class just to have a pointer to it).

Widget.hpp:

```
#include "Library.hpp"

namespace MyLibrary
{
    class Widget
    {
    private:
        Window * parent;
    };
}
```

Window.hpp:

```
#include "Library.hpp"

namespace MyLibrary
{
    class Window
    {
    private:
        std::vector<Widget*> widgets;
    };
}
```

Library.hpp:

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    class Window;
    class Widget;
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll probably go with Derek's suggestion as it seems generally easier to implement while still getting the same work done, though. Thanks for the input, though!

Answer (score 2):

It's generally better not to have such cyclic dependencies: they're a bit of a pain to code, frustrate logical reasoning about the code, testability etc..

They can be avoided easily anyway - you could keep some functors in the Components, then point them at the Container operations appropriate to the events being handled, or derive the Container from an abstract interface, so the Components can have a pointer to it and the Container derive therefrom.  Or the Components may be stored by (smart) pointer, with a derived type implementing virtual event handlers customised for the container.  There are lots of other possibilities e.g. if you want to avoid run-time overhead, consider CRTP or template policy classes.